# No php_mongodb.dll file in this archive?

Tags: mongodb

As it's written on this website: `http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/webdev-with-mongodb-part3/`, i need to unzip mongo-php-driver archive to get php_mongo.dll, but i can't find it...

Any help ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP driver for MongoDB can now be found on http://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb